# Заполнение массива в цикле

Tags: динамические-массивы

Пожалуйста, подскажите, как можно в .each(function(){}), динамически заполнить массив, чтобы привести его к такому виду:

```
var Coord = [[-123.77252789, 44.37857221], [-123.27252789, 44.17857221]];
```

Пробовал так, но результат отличается:

```
$.ajax({
            async: true,
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/Controller/Method',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",                
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                var Coord=[];
                $(data).each(function () {
                    Coord.push([this.x, this.y]);
                });
            }
        });
```

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Разобрался:

```
$.ajax({
            async: true,
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/Controller/Method',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",                
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                var Coord=[];
                $(data).each(function () {
                    Coord[index] = [this.x,this.y];
                });
            }
        });
```